# Drill down in Line Chart Highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, highcharts

I have a scenario as something similar to this.

https://jsfiddle.net/31om2f6d/

Note that the data plotted in x-axis and data inside series is a list of 50 values (in this example, I have mentioned 6 values.) I need to drilldown into another three line charts which indicates the sum of the counts.
For example, Point 50 in 2019.1 will be split into three points say(10,10,30) in the drilldown. Similarly the rest of the points as well.As a result, there should be 3 line charts when I drilldown from linechart of main page. Kindly help me out with this function. (The values for the drilldown is in the form of list as well.)

Note: I have been reading in forum like drilldown can be done only in point mapping and not when mapped in series. I am not sure if that is the exact behaivour. If so, kindly let me know how we can map a series of 50 dynamic data by points and drilldown from there.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
  colors: [
    '#470303', '#c40a0a', '#a34d4d', '#eda4a4'
  ]
});

Highcharts.chart('container-trend', {
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Trend'
  },
  exporting: {
    tableCaption: false,
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [2019.1, 2019.2, 2019.3, 2019.4, 2019.5, 2019.6]
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Counts '
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
      enableMouseTracking: true
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Total Counts',
    data: [50,70,30,40,50,20]
  }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 360px; 
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}
.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table thead tr, .highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
        <div id="container-trend" style="min-width: 310px; height: 320px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you like to achieve something like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f4bvud2q/?

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Total Counts',
    data: [{y: 50, drilldown: '2019.1'},70,30,40,50,20]
  }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: '2019.1',
            id: '2019.1',
            data: [10, 10, 30]
        }]
    }
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown.series

Comment: Thank you as always, Sebastian.It looks good. I have two quick questions. 

1) In series you have mapped one line graph, right? Is there anyway I can map more than one line charts in a same drilldown. 

2) If I have 20 data, Is there any efficient way like a loop or something in which I can map drilldown (Inside drilldown method in events class.)

Comment: @Ashwinkrishnan 1) you can use the `addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown` feature to add more series for drilldown, see: http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/uufrmerz/ 2) I am not sure here what do you have in mind, but you can trigger some function for the `drilldown.series` which you can customize to loop through the data - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pqhf0zsc/